# A general strategy to "strike" NT problems.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The question:
Given two natural numbers x and y that satisfies the following properties:

For every whole number z, if $$z(z + 1)(z + 2)(z + 3) ...(z + y - 1)(z + y)$$ is divisible by x, then exactly one of $$z, z + 1, z + 2, ..., z + y  - 1, z + y$$ is divisible by x.
Find all pairs of {x, y}.

One thing I noticed after practicing a lot of NT questions is that I struggle to solve such "simple" problems that involves "for every number ... that satisfies ..." since you can't brute force.

Are there like any general strategy on solving such questions? (P.S. I also need an answer to this question :)

Comment: That is why x = 2 and y = 3 is not a solution to this problem, since it does not satisfies the requirements asked. Also, this question was asked on a Whatsapp group.

Comment: Question edited.

Comment: one silly (or perhaps significant) idea that I have is to take $x$ to be a prime that's sufficiently large so that for a particular value of $y$ that you take, only one multiple of that prime comes up among $z, z + 1, z + 2, \dots z + y$. As I see, $(x,y) = (2,3)$ must have been eliminated as for even $z$, you'll be getting two even numbers among $z, z + 1, z + 2$...

Comment: Hmm, interesting idea.

Comment: For eg. , let $x = 5$. You can see that for $y =4$, you can only find one integer that is divisible by $5$

Comment: How about x = y + 1, with x prime?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133606/discussion-between-spectre-and-marioprix).

Comment: I think that the so-called "mistake" I noted yesterday was just as foolish as anything, because $0$ is a multiple of $5$ in the example. Plus your general rule works... I wonder how careless I was in having avoided $0$ as a multiple of $5$!

Comment: Oof I forgot about this question since I was on hospital a few days ago.... sorry about that.... I'm back now! Also, thanks Spectre!

Comment: hope you are fine :) And as you might have noticed in the comments below my answer, you can see that my answer is incomplete -  and I haven't tried to resolve the issue till now since I am very busy with my school tests.

Answer (score 0):

As I see in your comments and from the whole conversation, $x = y + 1$ is a good  choice for an attack strategy. I'm sorry for the carelessness I showed while considering the various ways in which we can get hit the problem down (you must have noted that I out of all my carelessness blurted out that one can't find a multiple of $5$ among $0,1,2,3,4$. In fact, $0$ is a multiple of $5$ ( $5 \times 0 = 0$)). Yes, $x = y + 1$ works.

A demonstration of that sort of a solution:
Let $y = 2 \implies x = 3$. You can certainly see,
From $0,1,2$ you have $0$ as a multiple of $3$.($z = 0$)
From $1,2,3$ you have $3$ as a multiple of $3$.($z = 1$)
$\dots$
And so on... we see that the taken strategy works fine!
My $(x, y) = (5,4)$ example works as well.
One thing we see is that (as a conjecture) $(x,y) = (k, k-1)$ for all $k > 1$ (I say $k > 1$ because if $k = 1$,$y = 0$ which is not a natural number).

Now into proving that the conjecture is right.
(Then shortest thing to say would be that there will always be a multiple of $n$ in a set of $n$ consecutive integers, whose proof I think I'll be typing up below)
Let $z \equiv l \pmod{x}, 0 \leq l < x$ 
$z + y \equiv x \pmod{x}$ where $y = x - l$. Notice that $0 \leq l <x, \therefore 0 < x - l \leq x$ ;($x - l \leq x$ when $ l= 0$).
Now observe the case where $l =0$(i.e., $x \mid z$ or $z \equiv 0 \pmod{x}$); we get $y = x$, thus $z + y \equiv x \equiv 0 \pmod{x}$, which means that out of $z, z + 1, z + 2, \dots z + y$, we'll have $2$ multiples of $x$, namely $z$ and $z + y$ ( $= z + x$, since we take $y = x - 0$). So we need $y < x$ (this is certainly supportive of the hypothesis that $y + 1 = x$).
When $y = x - 1$, we see that out of $z, z + 1, \dots z + x - 1$, there will always be a multiple of $x$. One can see that in the fact that on dividing any integer $a$ by another integer $b$, the remainder obtained will lie in the range $\lbrace 0, 1, 2, \dots b - 1 \rbrace$ as a consequence of the Euclidean division algorithm. In this case, $\lbrace 0, 1, 2, \dots x - 1 \rbrace$ are the remainders obtained on division of any integer by $x$. If $z \equiv l \pmod{x}$, addition of $x - l$ to $z$ will give a number divisible by $x$, whatsoever be the value of the integer $z$. Now I believe you can see why $y = x$ should be excluded as a possibility.
On further digging, we notice that no other value of $y$ that $x+1$ will show such a property as required by the question. So we conclude that $(x, y) = (k, k - 1)$ is the required general format of the natural number pairs.

**P.S.**: I suggest that you can wait for some more time till new solution pops up before clicking that "Accept" button to accept my answer.
**P.S.(2)**: I see that we have ore possible methods as well; I haven't verified them, but maybe you can try them and point out in the comments whether they are working or not.

Comment: Note your answer is incomplete. For example, with $x = 4$, then $y = 2$ works. Also, for all prime $p$ and positive integers $n$, then $x = p^n$ and any $1 \le y \le p - 1$ works as well. I'll leave it to you to confirm these cases, as well as to determine there are no other possibilities.

Comment: @JohnOmielan I guess I didn't mention that the only possibility is that I mentioned in my answer?? If yes, sorry, I shall edit it and add this lil info you've given. Thanks !

Comment: @JohnOmielan by confirming did you mean that I must put up a mathematical proof as in the answer above?? (I know it's an incomplete proof up there, possibly with many gaps)

Comment: By "confirming" I meant that, if just reading is insufficient, then checking to verify my other examples also work, as well as that there are no other possibilities. As for whether or not you "must put up a mathematical proof", if you want your answer to be complete, then you will need to do that. Finally, FYI, since I don't believe you can see this at your reputation, the question has $3$ close votes. However, the [timeline](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4368810/timeline) shows there were $3$ leave open reviews, so it's exited the close review.

Comment: @JohnOmielan Thanks for the information. Yes, even I felt that you must have wanted me to write a proof alongside the claim (sure, I'll give a try; only that I see a chance of me running into a state unsolvable with respect to my level of understanding in number theory). The brute force checking is just a bit tricky at times, as I see that claims that seem to hold true for most numbers may have exceptional cases. That was why I wanted to know from you if we needed a mathematical proof to verify the claim. I'll give a try and let you know once I'm done or if I'm stuck.

Comment: @JohnOmielan as for the close votes, I think the OP's silence is the main reason...